# Can I produce grinder card without breaking this patent?

Tags: us8636237

In reference to the patent: [US8636237](https://www.google.com/patents/US8636237)

Hello, I am planning to start producing new product which does not exist on the market yet. Problem is that one of its main parts is grinder card sticked inside of the product. We are not planning to use valleys which are main point of this patent (if I understand right) and not even any specific shape created from the grinding holes. Since the grinder card will be sticked inside of the product it will not fit into wallet anymore. Would I break any law by producing my product which contain grinder card manufactured without using these specific patented features?

thank you in advance for any advices.

Answer (score 1):

For you to infringe on a patent, you need to implement each and every step of at least one of the claims. In this patent's case, there is one independent claim and seven dependent claims. Always focus on the independent claims first. Here is claim 1:

> 1. A herb grinder comprising:
>
>    a metal sheet having a first surface and second surface opposite the first surface, the sheet being configured
>      to include, on the first surface, a plurality of grooves, each groove
>      extending parallel with one another and spaced apart from one another,
>      wherein the grooves and the first surface define, in cross section, a
>      square wave shape having valleys and peaks, wherein each valley has a
>      planar floor that is roughened to provide a finely abrasive surface,
>      and each peak has a planar cap that is not roughened;
>
>    a plurality of holes of a first type, the first type of hole extending from a peak to the second surface of the metal sheet;
>
>    a plurality of holes of a
>      second type, the second type of hole extending from a valley to the
>      second surface of the metal sheet.

If your product doesn't employ every aspect of claim 1 then you shouldn't infringe on this patent. Since I don't know everything about your product, I can't make such an evaluation. Even if I did have sufficient knowledge, I wouldn't since I'm not an attorney and don't provide legal advice.

Your best bet is to **consult with a patent attorney** to get a "freedom to operate" opinion. First, this will guide you as to whether this or other patents are going to be a problem for you. Second, a freedom to operate opinion may be able to provide protection from punitive damages which result from an infringement suit.